# Run sails new inside a docker container

Tags: docker, sails.js

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to create a sails project using it.
I have the following doubt:

I want to install sails only in the container, I don't want to run npm install -g sails in my host machine, it is correct to do that or I'm wrong?

Since I want to install sails only in the container, it is possible to create the project structure in the container using sails new command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer**

Yes you can execute any sails command as though you had sails installed on your host machine. Once you have a container running, you can use the `docker exec` command to execute any command within the container, for example:

```
docker exec container-name sails new my-sails-project
```

Or you can connect to the container's shell and execute commands directly:

```
docker exec -it container-name /bin/sh
sails new my-sails-project
```

Both these approaches will create a new sails project *inside* the container in the `/my-sails-project` directory.

**The long answer**

As mentioned above, if you execute the `sails new` command using one of those two approaches, it will create the project *inside* the container. If you want to access the project outside the container (on your host machine), you need to create a docker volume to mount the folder inside your container to your host, for example:

```
docker run ... --volume "/some/path/to/dev/folder/on/your/host/machine:/my-sails-project
```

This will let you have access to all the files created by `sails new` on your host in the specified directory. One more thing to note is that if you run the sails server inside the container using `sails lift`, you will need to expose that port so that the server is accessible on your host machine, you can achieve this with the `--port` flag to create a port forward mapping as follows:

```
docker run ... --port 1337:1337
```

where port `1337` the default port used by the sails server.

**Bringing it all together**

You can simplify starting up your container by including the above startup configuration in a `docker-compose` file, and use that to start up your container. [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a tool that allows you to decoratively specify how a container will be run, an example of what your `docker-compse.yml` file would look like:

```
version: '3'
container_name: sails-dev
ports:
  - 1337:1337
volumes:
  - /some/path/to/dev/folder/on/your/host/machine:/my-sails-project
```

Then you can start up your project by running `docker-compose up` from the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file (or use the `-f` flag to specify the path to it).

If you find you're running the `sails` commands often, you can put the `docker exec` command in a script and call that with whatever arguments passed to it. If you added this script to your path, you could call rails commands straight from your host as though it were installed natively, eg:

```
#!/bin/sh
docker exec -it sails-dev sails $*
```

Then you can run `sails` commands through `./sails.sh some-sails-command`.

Comment: Happy to help @clluiz. If this solves your difficulties, please also mark the answer as 'accepted', so the next person will know whether or not this works for your problem.